# What is the real purpose of @OneToOne in Spring boot hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, one-to-one

I have two entities named **Users** and **Dependents**. I want to establish a **OneToOne** relationship between these two entities. As the real meaning of OneToOne states that -

> Every user in the Users entity should have one and only one dependent.
>   And every dependent in the Dependents entity should only be related to
>   one and only one user.

But when I add @OneToOne to Dependents entity it does not stop me from adding two dependents to the same user. What is the real use of @OneToOne
or any other relationship annotations like @ManyToMany, @OneToMany, @ManyToOne?

**Users.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String teamName;
    private Integer salary;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(Integer id, String name, String teamName, Integer salary) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public Integer getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(Integer salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

**Dependents.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Dependents {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String relationship;
    @OneToOne
    private Users user;

    public Dependents() {
    }

    public Dependents(int id, String name, String relationship) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.relationship = relationship;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRelationship() {
        return relationship;
    }

    public void setRelationship(String relationship) {
        this.relationship = relationship;
    }

    public Users getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Users user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

And in my **DependentsService.java** I am saving the Dependents object like-

```
public Dependents addNewDependent(Integer userId, Dependents dependent) {
        dependent.setUser(usersRepository.getOne(userId));
        return dependentsRepository.save(dependent);
}
```

Here I am fetching the user from the Users entity with the passed userId and storing it in Dependents object. When I pass the same userId for two or more dependents it will fetch the same user from Users entity and store it in Dependents entity. This violated OneToOne relationship. Can someone please explain to me, **how can I achieve true OneToOne relationship? And also please explain what is the true purpose of relationship annotations like - @OneToOne, @OneToMany, @ManyToOne and @ManyToMany?**

Comment: You say "therefore" - that sounds as if you have reasoned about what may happen, but haven't actually tried it. What actually happens to the database when you call this multiple times with same userID and different dependent?

Comment: @Sunil it will not restrict you to add data in the dependent table if you have id from Parent table but when you add  OneToOne mapping then it will give you single record from dependent table

Comment: if you have data like multiple records in second table then you can use @oneToMany Mapping

Comment: @GaneshPatil thank you for responding, I got your point that It does not restrict and your suggestion to use `@OneToMany` annotation. My questions is when I can achieve the same thing with `@OneToOne` or `@OneToMany`, what is the purpose of the annotations?

Comment: @Thomas_Timbul thank you for your observation and suggession of `therefore`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one):

> From a relational database point of view, the underlying schema is identical to the unidirectional @ManyToOne association, as the client-side controls the relationship based on the foreign key column.

...

> A much more natural mapping would be if the Phone were the parent-side, therefore pushing the foreign key into the PhoneDetails table. This mapping requires a **bidirectional @OneToOne** association

...

> When using a bidirectional @OneToOne association, **Hibernate enforces the unique constraint** upon fetching the child-side. If there are more than one children associated with the same parent, **Hibernate will throw** a org.hibernate.exception.**ConstraintViolationException**.

So you should use a bidirectional one-to-one association.

Additional info: [The best way to map a @OneToOne relationship with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: I will accept this answer if I get to know what do these annotations do internally? Currently, it answers half of my question.

Comment: @Sunil what do you mean 'internally'? If you look into documentation you can find the table structure of both side of association, for example...

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate won't do any extra checks to make sure, the record already exists. It is your responsibility to write the code which satisfies the OneToOne relation (it depends on your UI screens as well). If you still want to throw some exception, make your primary key as Foreign key in dependent table. Then you get DB exception.

Comment: If Hibernate does not do any extra work, what does it exactly do when I put any of these annotations?